# Undefined index for Session variable

Tags: php, session

I am setting a session variable when a submit button is pressed like so:

```
<?php
$submit = @$_POST["submit"];
if($submit){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
}
?>

<form action="add.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

However, in the page `add.php` when I do:

```
print_r($_SESSION['id'];
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: id
```

I'm new to sessions so still trying to come to grips with them, but I thought the part where I do `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` is where I define the index `id` to be the value of the `$id` variable? Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

In case you're wondering if I am using `session_start()`: At the top of the page with the form, I include my header page which at the top contains `require_once './init.php';`. At the top of my `add.php` I just have the line `require_once './init.php';` (I do not include the header file in `add.php` as this page will redirect as soon as it has executed its code.

In the `init.php` file is the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'configurate.php'; //database info
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should define a value for `$id` before you assing the value of `$id` to something else

Comment: Have you put `session_start()` on top of your 2 pages?

Answer (score 0):

you should call `session_start()` before setting any values in `$_SESSION`

change your code like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$submit = @$_POST["submit"];
if($submit){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
}
?>

<form action="add.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- I hope you have initialized your session via [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before setting and retrieving the value from `$_SESSION`
- if the value submitted via `$_POST["submit"]` compares to false (e.g. `""` or `0`) your condition `if($submit)` won't succeed, better use `if (isset($_POST['submit']` instead